# Placing text and pictures together

Tags: horizontal-alignment, diagrams, text

I would like to obtain the result shown in the image below. There is no problem with the text nor with the picture. I use enumerate and tikzpicture environment for them. The PROBLEM is I don't know how to place the picture alongside the text.

For explanation purposes, there is no need to replicate text or the picture, use any simple list and tikzpicture. Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

**Edit**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace,parskip}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,systeme,siunitx}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,hmargin={2.5cm,2.5cm},vmargin={2.5cm},headsep={0.5cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{paracol}

\begin{document}
\columnratio{0.75}
\onehalfspacing

\begin{enumerate}
    \item blah blah blah item 1
\begin{paracol}{2}
   \begin{leftcolumn}
      \item Un recipiente contiene agua y aceite. Calcule:
      \begin{enumerate}
        \item El ángulo de refracción de un rayo de luz que, procedente del fondo del recipiente, incide en la capa de aceite con un ángulo de \ang{40}.
        \item El ángulo de incidencia de un rayo de luz para que, incidiendo desde el aceite hacia el agua, se produzca la reflexión total.
        \item Las frecuencias del haz de luz en el agua y en el aceite, si su longitud de onda es de 450 nm.
    \end{enumerate}
    \emph{Datos}: $n_{agua}=1,33$, $n_{acaite}=1.45$, $c=3\cdot10^{8}$ \unit{m.s^{-1}}
   \end{leftcolumn}
   \begin{rightcolumn}
      \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[yellow!30,fill=yellow!10] (0,2) rectangle (3,1);
    \draw[cyan!30,fill=cyan!10] (0,1) rectangle (3,0);
    \draw[very thick] (0,2.3) -- (0,0) -- (3,0) -- (3,2.3);
    \node at (1.5,1.5) {aceite};
    \node at (1.5,0.5) {agua};
    \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{rightcolumn}
\end{paracol}
\item blah blah blah item 3
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Now the idea is to place the image at medium height, not at the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be better solutions, but I usually use paracol in such cases:

```
\usepackage{paracol}

\begin{document}
\columnratio{0.7} % 0,7 of the widths for the text, rest for the image
\begin{paracol}{2}
   \begin{leftcolumn}
      text, list, stuff
   \end{leftcolumn}
   \begin{rightcolumn}
      \vspace*{-1.5em}
      image
   \end{rightcolumn}
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

edit: Added the code in question to have the desired spacing:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace,parskip}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,systeme,siunitx}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,hmargin={2.5cm,2.5cm},vmargin={2.5cm},headsep={0.5cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{paracol}

\begin{document}
    \columnratio{0.75}
    \setlength\columnsep{0pt}
    \onehalfspacing
    
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item blah blah blah item 1
        \begin{paracol}{2}
            \begin{leftcolumn}
                \item Un recipiente contiene agua y aceite. Calcule:
                \begin{enumerate}
                    \item El ángulo de refracción de un rayo de luz que, procedente del fondo del recipiente, incide en la capa de aceite con un ángulo de \ang{40}.
                    \item El ángulo de incidencia de un rayo de luz para que, incidiendo desde el aceite hacia el agua, se produzca la reflexión total.
                    \item Las frecuencias del haz de luz en el agua y en el aceite, si su longitud de onda es de 450 nm.
                \end{enumerate}
                \emph{Datos}: $n_{agua}=1,33$, $n_{acaite}=1.45$, $c=3\cdot10^{8}$ \unit{m.s^{-1}}
            \end{leftcolumn}
            \begin{rightcolumn}
                \vspace*{1cm}\hspace*{-20pt}
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                    \draw[yellow!30,fill=yellow!10] (0,2) rectangle (3,1);
                    \draw[cyan!30,fill=cyan!10] (0,1) rectangle (3,0);
                    \draw[very thick] (0,2.3) -- (0,0) -- (3,0) -- (3,2.3);
                    \node at (1.5,1.5) {aceite};
                    \node at (1.5,0.5) {agua};
                \end{tikzpicture}
            \end{rightcolumn}
        \end{paracol}
        \item blah blah blah item 3
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Here is how it looks like for me:

[image]

Comment: Ok, thank you. That is one step forward. But why the image does appear at the top of it column? Is there a positioning option?

Comment: It should, actually, can you post your code which displays the problem?

Comment: Well, there is the code.

Comment: Not sure why this is happening, but you can shift the image up with a `\vspace*{-1.5em}`, I edited the code accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your comment, you actually don't want it to appear at the top. Then you need a positive vspace.

Comment: ah, well, yes, \vspace may be a solution, it is like american tape, all-purpose solution. Your answer provides the derired effect in the text, so I will accept it as the answer. Thank you.

Comment: One more thing. Ok, I can play with heigth usin \vspace, but what can I do for lateral displacement? There is a space gap between image and text, making the image "invade" the margins of the page, so I'd like to move it to left. Any solution for that?

Comment: You can set the distance between the columns to zero with `\setlength\columnsep{0pt}` and/or add a negative horizontal space in front of the right column with `\hspace*{-10pt}`.

Comment: It does not work at all.

Comment: I added the code, note the vspace and hspace commands at the beginning of the rightcolumn environment!

Comment: that is what i did, and I always got the same warning "Overfull \hbox (20.61763pt too wide) in paragraph ...". I have even used \hspace*{-20cm} and the warning is exactly the same, i.e., the picture does not move at all.

Comment: I added an image demonstrating how it looks like for me. I don't get a warning as well.

Comment: Yes, I guess by moving it to left yo also avoid the warning. I don't know why it does not work in my case. I am using Overleaf.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have an Overleaf account so I cannot test it myself, I'd suggest to create a new question regarding the Overleaf issue such that it gets more attention!

Comment: Ok, solved. Previously I had added a flushleft enviroment to try something but I forgot to remove it. Now I got the same result. Thank you!

Comment: Great! Your're welcome!